# Jacobi's original reference in Riemann's paper

Tags: riemann-zeta-function

In Riemann's original paper on the zeta function, page 3, he uses a result by Jacobi, and gives as reference: "Fund. S. 184".

Could someone provide a digital link, or exact reference, for this result? I want to see how Jacobi obtained the proof originally, but can't pinpoint the reference. Is it included in Jacobi's classic: "fundamenta novae..."??

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Available online at https://archive.org/details/fundamentanovat00jacogoog

Here's p. 184, for what it's worth:

[image: p. 184 of Jacobi's Fundamenta Novae]

Answer (score 7):

*Fundamenta Nova Theoriae Functionum Ellipticarum*. Königsberg 1829, S.184, §65 (found [here](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Seite:RiemannPrim1859.djvu/3#cite_ref-1))